# Arrange select query in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a query :

```
select channel, status, sum(quantity::integer) 
from sale group by channel,status;
```

this is giving the following output:

```
channel  status       quantity
Arham    Return       1801
Arham    DISPATCHED   49934
Arham    CANCELLED    1791
Arham    DELIVERED    22
```

But I want this output like:

```
channel   return   DISPATCHED   CANCELLED  DELIVERED  
Arham     1801     49934        1791       22
```

Is it possible in postgresql? 
If yes then how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exploit Boolean to integer conversion giving either 0 or 1, then multiply by that:

```
select channel
     , sum((status = 'Return') :: int * quantity :: int) as return
     , sum((status = 'DISPATCHED') :: int * quantity :: int) as DISPATCHED
     , sum((status = 'CANCELLED') :: int * quantity :: int) as CANCELLED
     , sum((status = 'DELIVERED') :: int * quantity :: int) as DELIVERED
from sale
group by channel
```

An equivalent solution is using `case`/`when`/`then`, for example:

```
sum(case when status = 'Return' then quantity :: int else 0 end)
```

Comment: @YAM Comparisons like `status = 'Return'` result in either true or false. When you convert true to an integer, you get one. When you convert false to an integer, you get zero. Multiplying anything by zero gives zero, and multiplying anything by one gives the original value. `sum` effectively ignores zeros.

Comment: ya one thing i forget .    status may be dynamic

Comment: Then you should ask a new question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the `crosstab` function you can do this using filtered aggregates:

```
select channel,
       sum(quantity) filter (where status = 'Return') as return_amount,
       sum(quantity) filter (where status = 'DISPATCHED') as dispatched,
       sum(quantity) filter (where status = 'CANCELLED') as cancelled,
       sum(quantity) filter (where status = 'DELIVERED') as delivered
from sale
group by channel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html).

First you need to create extension

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;
```

and the query is

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
      'select channel::text
             ,status
             ,sum(quantity::integer) 
       from sale group by channel,status')  
AS ct ("channel" text, "Return" int, "DISPATCHED" int, "CANCELLED" int, "DELIVERED" int);
```

Comment: it is giving error :   `ERROR:  invalid return type
DETAIL:  SQL rowid datatype does not match return rowid datatype.`

Comment: what is the datatype of each column ?

Comment: every column have varchar data type initially.

Comment: @yam: why are you storing `quantity` as a `varchar`? Never, ever store numbers in `varchar` columns. Don't do that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right. I will update all my database when the processing part is complete. after that i will improve my database in standard form.   thanks